# How can I generate database tables manually in controller with codefirst migration faster?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I started a custom CMS using C# and MVC code first. I added a controller called Setup and in the setup controller action GenrateDatabase I get DatabaseName Initial catalog User Id and database password after that I generate data base connection string and update it in web.config and run seed method in bellow code.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GenrateDatabase([Bind(Include = "DataSource,InitialCatalog,UserId,Password")] Database database)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (database.GenrateDatabase())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Register");
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Mmm, something went wrong, Please check your data and try again.");
        return View(database);
    }
```

and my database class is :

```
public class Database
{
    [Required]
    public string DataSource { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string InitialCatalog { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    //$"Data Source={DataSource};Initial Catalog={InitialCatalog};User Id ={UserId}; Password = {Password};";
    private string ConnectionString => $"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Store;Integrated Security=SSPI";

    public bool GenrateDatabase()
    {
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        section.ConnectionStrings["goomooshCNSdb"].ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        configuration.Save();
        return (GenrateTables()) ? true : false;
    }

    private bool GenrateTables()
    {
        if (db.Database.Exists())
        {
            //var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration();
            Migrations.Configuration configuration = new Migrations.Configuration();
            configuration.ContextType = typeof(ApplicationDbContext);
            var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
            migrator.Configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
            var migrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
            if (migrations.Any())
            {
                var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
                var script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(null, migrations.Last());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(script))
                {
                    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

when I run my project and enter data and submit the form all codes run perfectly but the problem is db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script); takes too much time and never finish after maybe 10 minutes.

When I check database on SQL Server code created all tables and every things need but code never redirect to register action.

How can I Create this class and method faster like wordpress or other CMS?